# Error installing ruby-ldap in Debian

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ldap, debian

I'm trying to install ruby-ldap and it doesn't work.

Tried installing libsasl2-dev and libldap-dev didn't help.

Tried `apt-get install ruby-ldap` gem ignores it.

Tried deleting `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-ldap*` & `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/cache/ruby-ldap*` and re installing didn't help.

Anyone had a similar problem?

```
# gem install ruby-ldap
Fetching: ruby-ldap-0.9.12.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-ldap:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
--with-openldap2
checking for ldap.h... yes
checking for lber.h... yes
checking for ldap_ssl.h... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/crypto.h... yes
checking for main() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... yes
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lresolv... yes
checking for main() in -llber... yes
checking for main() in -lldap_r... yes
checking for main() in -lldap... yes
checking for ldap_init() in ldap.h... yes
checking for ldap_set_option()... yes
checking for ldap_get_option()... yes
checking for ldap_start_tls_s()... yes
checking for ldap_memfree()... yes
checking for ldap_perror()... yes
checking for ldap_sort_entries()... yes
checking for ldapssl_init()... no
checking for ldap_sslinit()... no
checking for ldap_sasl_bind_s()... yes
checking for ldap_compare_s()... yes
checking for ldap_add_ext_s()... yes
checking for ldap_compare_ext_s()... yes
checking for ldap_delete_ext_s()... yes
checking for ldap_modify_ext_s()... yes
checking for ldap_search_ext_s()... yes
checking for ldap_unbind_ext_s()... yes
checking for ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s()... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling saslconn.c
saslconn.c: In function ‘rb_ldap_conn_sasl_bind’:
saslconn.c:178:7: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
saslconn.c:200:7: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [saslconn.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `gcc` compiler seems to be too angry to warnings. Would you try to enforce no format check during compilation:

```
gem install ruby-ldap -- --with-cflags=\"-Wformat=0\"
```

The latter should override the default `CFLAGS`, supplied by `ruby-ldap` maintainers and stop treating format warnings as errors. If this will not help, you always may download the source of `ruby-ldap`, find the `Makefile` for native extensions and remove `-Werror=format-security` string from there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yup that was it, aparenty [this](http://wiki.debian.org/Hardening#DEB_BUILD_HARDENING_FORMAT_.28gcc.2Fg.2B-.2B-_-Wformat_-Wformat-security_-Werror.3Dformat-security.29) is the reasson. Thanks a lot!!